# WKWebView reloads and then goes blank for a local index.html file

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have this file that I'm trying to reload but when I reload it I get the screen that is supposed to show up and then a blank screen until I hit reload again. I'm not sure why I'm getting this blank screen. Also, I do not get anything from

```
- (void)webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate:(WKWebView *)webView {}
```

nor

```
-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
```

Here's my viewController.m file I have the index.html file in the same directory as it does load once but I'm not sure if webkit is crashing or where

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
#import <JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


NSString *localURL;
NSURLRequest *urlRequest;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [super viewDidLoad];

  JSContext *ctx = [[JSContext alloc] init];
  ctx[@"console"][@"log"] = ^(NSString *message) {
    NSLog(@"Javascript log: %@", message);
};

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
// [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
//_webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
// _webView.navigationDelegate = self.webView ;
// _webView.UIDelegate = self;
//[self.view addSubview:_webView ];

_webView= [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 500, 500)];
 localURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index"  ofType:@"html"];
urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL   fileURLWithPath:localURL]];
[_webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
[self.view addSubview:_webView];

//button
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(reload)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [button setTitle:@"Reload" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  button.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 20.0, 100.0, 50.0);
  button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor;
  [self.view addSubview:button];

}
 - (void)webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate:(WKWebView *)webView {
 // Reload current page, since we have crashed the WebContent process
 // (most likely due to memory pressure)

 NSLog(@"most likely due to memory pressure reloaded");
 [webView reload];
}
-(void)reload{
  NSLog(@"reloading now");
  [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

  //[self.webView stopLoading];
 // [self loadView];
  //[_webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 NSLog(@"memory issue");
}


//- (IBAction)rButton:(UIButton *)sender {
// NSLog(@"Well we didnt crash");
//  [self.webView reload];
//}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is due to a termination of the web the delegate function webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate will be called.

In your case it looks that you didn't set the viewController as the navigationDelegate of the webview:

```
webview.navigationDelegate = self
```